# Yii2: Как в GridView::widget() можно указать произвольную колонку с произвольным содержимым?

Tags: yii2, gridview

В [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html), как обычно, все очень поверхностно.

Ответ, желательно, сразу в виде примера, как-то так:

```php
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'code',
            'name',
            'population',
            'id',
            [
                'attribute' => 'imageFile',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function($data) {
                    return '<img src="/uploads/'.$data->imageFile.'" width="200" alt="" />';
                }
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавляете еще колонку и устанавливайте ей заголовок и значение.

Примерно так:

```
    [
        'label' => 'myLabel',
        'format' => 'html',
        'value' => function($data) {
            ...
            return myValue;
        }
    ],
```